# Removing object required message with cancel msgbox but does not perform delete action

Tags: vba, excel

Now i can delete but whenever i fail to highlight a cell to delete it gives me an object required . i tried removing the error message with a cancel message box but it does not perform the delete action. Would need help to correct my mistake!

```
Sub deletetry2()

    Dim R As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", , , , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
    R.delete

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.InputBox` is more flexible than `InputBox`. It's last parameter is a type parameter, with type 8 corresponding to selecting a range with the mouse.

Sample code:

```
Sub DeleteCells()
    Dim R As Range
    On Error GoTo err_handler 'if user hits "Cancel"
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", , Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    R.Delete
err_handler:
    'any needed error handling code here
End Sub
```

On edit: I modified the code to incorporate brettdj's excellent suggestion to include the selection as the default range. I also added some error trapping to catch the case that the user clicks "Cancel" on the input box. In this case the error handling is to just exit the function, though certainly more involved error handling could be appropriate for your specific case.

A final thought -- make sure that you really want to `delete` the cells. That is sometimes a problematic move since it causes other cells to shift around to fill the vacuum. In many cases `Clear` or `ClearContents` can delete what you want to delete without effecting other cells.

Comment: Good approach. Would add Selection.Address as the default option for the Inputbox

Comment: @brettdj Good idea. I modified the code to reflect it. Thanks.